# GDB only read 1 character from STDIN

Tags: debugging, unix, assembly, gdb, nasm

Currently I'm now learning assembly language, out of curiosity, I want to see how my program that was coded using assembly work under the hood, so I load up `GDB` (with `-tui` and `layout asm` ) and start debugging.

It came at my surprise when `GDB` asking for `STDIN` input, it only take 1 character and then stop taking others even if I'm not pressing `enter`.

I tried again in terminal, it's working fine and my program can take multiple `STDIN` input without any problem.

Here I provide partion from my testing assembly, this problem is reproducible with following assembly :

```
global main

segment .bss                        ; hold uninitialize buffer

szinput     resb    10              ; declare 10 bytes uninitialize buffer
nszinput    equ     $ - szinput     ; equ is meaning constant

segment .text

main:

    pusha
    mov     eax, DWORD 3            ; read syscall
    mov     ebx, DWORD 0            ; 0 is stdin file descriptor
    mov     ecx, szinput            ; void *buf
    mov     edx, nszinput           ; size_t count
    int     80h                     ; invoke syscall
    popa
    ret
```

Note that this assembly is for NASM assembler.

Running `gdb --version`, and this is the result : `GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1`

Comment: 0 is stdin. AFAIK, either 0 or 1 will work for sys_read or sys_write (dunno why). Maybe gdb doesn't like it?

Comment: @FrankKotler, OMG, what a silly mistake I made, but changing my file descriptor code to 0 still don't solve my problem.

Comment: By the way, I edited my question to not confuse this mistake for others.